# How to restore a user story from recyclebin through Rally Node Rest API

Tags: node.js, rest, api, rally, recycle-bin

I am trying to restore a User Story from Recycle bin, how do i do it (I only have the objectID of the user story available)?

Is there any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to currently do this via WSAPI.  The unsupported, undocumented way to do this is via the private /slm/recyclebin/restore.sp endpoint.  You can see how it's used if you go to the recycle bin page and restore an item via the gear menu.

Comment: I get the response 'We're Sorry'

Comment: hmm, could you post your code you're using to access the endpoint?  sounds like it's returning a server 500, so the parameters are probably not quite right...

Comment: url = slm/recyclebin/restore.sp?cpoid=12345&projectScopeUp=false&projectScopeDown=true&_slug=%2Frecyclebin_1&oid=6789
` request({
 url: url,
 proxy: rallyUtil.proxyURL,
 headers: {ZSESSIONID: rallyConfig.apiKey}
}, function (error, response, body) {}) `

Comment: hmm, i wonder if api keys don't work on that endpoint.  i can't say i've ever tried to do this, so it's entirely possible that you just can't do it by design...

Comment: @KyleMorse Is there any update to this?  I'm currently in the same predicament with ~1300 test cases I need to restore from the recycle bin... Is there still no way to restore artifacts via the RallyRestApi (ideally) or some other way (programmatically)?